# How To Update a layout in onActivityCreated() of Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am inflating a layout in `onCreateView()` of the `Fragment`,On the Activity created() of the `Fragment`,I am retreving the data from the `DataBase` and updating the values in the layout from the `DataBase` which i inflated earlier.

```
LinearLayout main = null;
        if (rootView instanceof LinearLayout)
            main = (LinearLayout) rootView;
        main.removeAllViews();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
        View inflatedLayout = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.nodata, null, false);
        if (main != null)
            main.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

Problem which i am facing is if I am getting no data,I am trying to inflate nodata XML(No `DataView`),`onActivityCreated()` of the fragment by removing all the elements of rootView,NoDataXML is  getting inflated,But UI Alignment is not happening,Layout is not occupying entire width of screen,it looks it `wrapcontent`,I gave `matchparent` to width and height of nodataxml layout

Anyone knows standard way of dealing this problem.

Comment: can you please post both your fragment layout.xml and the no_data.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,I am able to get it to center,by programmatically doing it out,instead of xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Usual way of dealing with such situation is just have 2 child layouts in your root Fragment view: first for loaded data, second - no data layout. Usual no data layout is tiny view, so there is no any overhead for system. And play with view visibilities inside onActivityCreated().

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/loaded_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/no_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Inside you onActivityCreated do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View noDataView = getView().findViewById(R.id.no_data);
    View loadedData = getView().findViewById(R.id.loaded_data);
    noDataView.setVisibility(isDataLoaded ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    loadedData.setVisibility(isDataLoaded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
     // display your data
}
```